# How can I quickly export text from an Android application?

Tags: android

I need to export the text generated by a Camera.Parameters object so that I can check what features are available.

```
Camera.Parameters cParam = getCameraInstance().getParameters();
Log.w("kavster", cParam.flatten());
```

How can I easily save the text that I am writing to the log instance with the flatten function to a file?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Comment: Do you mean as a one off or as part of your app process?  If it's as a one off, highlight the lines in the Logcat and press the disk icon in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable add the external storage permissions (`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`) in your manifest, then use `Context.getExternalFilesDir()` to get the external SD card location where you can write data.  From there it's just a matter of creating an output file and writing your text into it.